# Basic generic methods and how to call a method from non-generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I need help with generic methods and generics in general.

Here is the spec that I'm stuck with:

In the MyPets class above, add a method that takes a T as a parameter. This method, called myGenericMethod, will call makeNoise.  Call the makeNoise method for both of your pets inside this method.

Question is how do I call the makeNoise method from Animal Class (non-generic class). Do I have to use reflection?

```
    public class MyPets<T>{

//creating the myGenericMethod with T as its parameter.

    public void myGenericMethod(T t){

// How do I call the makeNoise() from Animal class here? 

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Animal` and `MyPets`?  What do you _want_ it to be?

Comment: I have Dog and Cat class that extends Animal. Basically In the main class, I create 1 dog and 1 cat object, then parameterized with the generic class created from MyPets class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need your generic type declaration to reflect that it extends Animal:

```
public class MyPets<T extends Animal> {
  public void myGenericMethod(T t) {
    t.makeNoise();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either drop the type parameter from `MyPets` and make `myGenericMethod` just take an `Animal`, or declare `T` as a *bounded wildcard* that must be `Animal` or some subtype:

```
class MyPets<T extends Animal> {
  public void myGenericMethod(T t) {
    // you can call Animal methods on t here
  }
}
```

Another thing you *could* do is just cast `t` to `Animal`, i.e. `Animal animalT = (Animal) t;`. But if you're doing that, then there's no point in declaring `myGenericMethod` as taking a `T` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. You and GriffeyDog have the same answer that I'm looking for. It works the way I want it to be!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your object as :

```
 MyPets<Animal> obj;
```

You call it :

```
obj.myGenericMethod(Animal aimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to amend your `MyPets` class like so:

```
public class MyPets<T extends Animal> {
   public void myGenericMethod(T t) {
       t.makeNoise()
    }
}
```

Now that you have a generic `MyPets` class that restricts `T` to instance of `Animal`, and you know that all instances of `Animal` have a `makeNoise` method, you can safely call `T#makeNoise()` in `myGenericMethod`.

This allows you to solve your problem as follows:

```
MyPets<Dog> myDog;
MyPets<Cat> myCat;

myDog = new MyPets<Dog>();
myDog.myGenericMethod(new Dog());

myCat = new MyPets<Cat>();
myCat.myGenericMethod(new Cat());
```

Note that the following is also technically correct, although it rather defeats the purpose of using generics in the first place:

```
MyPets<Animal> myPet;

myPet = new MyPets<Animal>();
myPet.myGenericMethod(new Dog());
myPet.myGenericMethod(new Cat());
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have understood the concept now :).